# O que devo colocar dentro do parentese?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

Olá estou começando a programar agora e estava acompanhando uma video aula e seguindo os passos do professor, porem chegou em uma parte que ele instalou o sqlite, porém a versão dele era anterior a minha e mudou alguma coisa dentro do Database.js do sqlite, depois de muito quebrar a cabeça eu descobri, porem eu nao sei como proceder justamente por estar muito inciante ainda...

Quando escrevo `const dbConnection = sqlite.open()`

dentro dos parenteses do .open aparece o balão escrito

> open(config: ISqlite.Config): Promise<Database<Database, Statement>>

dentro do arquivo Database.js na parte do open() está assim :

```
open() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let { filename, mode, driver } = this.config;
        if (!filename) {
            throw new Error('sqlite: filename is not defined');
        }
        if (!driver) {
            throw new Error('sqlite: driver is not defined');
        }
        if (mode) {
            this.db = new driver(filename, mode, err => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve();
            });
        }
        else {
            this.db = new driver(filename, err => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

o que eu devo escrever dentro dos parenteses?

na video aula o professor escrevia assim:

```
const dbConnection = sqlite.open('banco.sqlite', { Promise})
```

mas já sei que assim nao da certo

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando inicializar o banco de forma assíncrona, por isso a promessa.

As [promessas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) precisam ser resolvidas pra você ver algum resultado, então você tem duas opções:

```
async function conectaNoBanco(){
  const banco = await sqlite.open('dados de conexao')
  return banco
}

const conexao = await conectaNoBanco()
```

ou:

```
sqlite.open('dados de conexao').then(database => {resto do teu codigo})
```